# How to escape HTML attributes in strings.xml?

Tags: android, xml, localization

I'm supplying XML strings files to Android developers and confused about escaping rules when using HTML styles.

[The documentation here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StylingWithHTML) only talks about embedding `<b>`, `<i>` and `<u>` tags without escaping, but it also shows that you can use `Html.fromHtml` with any string of HTML.

So how should a chunk of HTML like `<font color="red">"Quote"</font>` appear in the strings.xml file?

As font tags can have attributes and quotes should be escaped, how should attribute quoting be handled?

The following is invalid XML, so clearly this is wrong:

```
<string name="eg_1"><font color=\"red\">\"Quote\"</font></string>
```

Should just the XML attributes be left unescaped?

```
<string name="eg_2"><font color="red">\"Quote\"</font></string>
```

It's valid XML, but seems wrong to have different escaping rules in the string.

Perhaps CDATA should be used to simply protect the entire string?

```
<string name="eg_3"><![CDATA[<font color=\"red\">\"Quote\"</font>]]></string>
```

Or even just escape it?

```
<string name="eg_4">&lt;font color=\"red\"&gt;\"Quote\"&lt;/font&gt;</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

> So how should a chunk of HTML like "Quote" appear in the strings.xml file?

Use `CDATA`, per your third sample above.

Comment: Thanks. And with the slashed quotes on the whole of the CDATA content, yes?

Comment: Also, just curious: It's obviously prettier than the fully escaped example, but are eg_3 and eg_4 equivalent to the Android parser?

Comment: @Tim: I don't think that you need the backslashes in eg_3 or eg_4. Those should be equivalent.

Comment: I'm even more confused about when and why backslashes are required then. The documentation on this is really poor. I get that there's a difference between how you might use the string at runtime (`String.format` vs `Html.fromHtml`) but surely the escaping rules in the XML should be consistent.

Comment: @Tim: I have used `CDATA` with HTML content in a string resource in the past. I have not tried it with HTML with attributes on tags. `CDATA` itself does not need the backslashes, and I suspect that the `CDATA` *also* is sufficient to handle the quotation marks. You will simply have to try it.

Answer (score 2):

The first example is an invalid XML (as you said).
The second example is an invalid strings.xml file.
The third example should be like this:

```
<string name="eg_3"><![CDATA[<font color="red">"Quote"</font>]]></string>
```

The fourth example is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I'm clear - what is the factor that determines that the double quotes are left un-slashed in your example?